# Swift - NSURLComponents how to handle passwords with special characters NTML Auth

Tags: ios, swift

I am using NSURLComponents like so:

```
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "https://example.com/api/");
urlComponents?.user = "username";
urlComponents?.password = "p@ssword";
```

Which gives me the URL:

> https://username:p%40ssword@example.com/api/

and this does not work with my api which needs NTML Auth. When I use a password that does not have special characters it does work.

Is there away to get around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902483/1801544 ? Might not be possible?

Comment: So according to that I can't use special characters?

Comment: I am going to switch to Alamofire works there

Comment: I guess it's because it uses `URLCredential` which you could use?